# IPSEC on linux with multiple remote ISP

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipsec, multicast, routes

I have configured 2 ipsec VPN connection from my linux server to my clients locations. the reason being the client has two ISPs a primary and a secondary on. The client wants to switch to secondary automatically when the primary is down.

When two different tunnels are configured through different remote Tunnel Termination Point the packets are being lost.

how do i configure such a way that the secondary goes up when the primary is down.

Comment: Please clarify the used IPSec implementation and whether it supports MOBIKE.